# CFString memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks, core-foundation

I have narrowed down a memory leak to the following code

```
CFStringRef CFDataToString(CFDataRef data)
{
    UInt8* buf = malloc(CFDataGetLength(data));

    CFDataGetBytes(data, CFRangeMake(0, CFDataGetLength(data)), buf);

    CFMutableStringRef output = CFStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFDataGetLength(data) * 2);

    for(int i = 0; i < CFDataGetLength(data); i++) {
        CFStringAppendFormat(output, NULL, CFSTR("%02x"), buf[i]);
    }

    free(buf);
    CFRelease(data);

    return output;
}
```

Below is the code used in context, some methods has been simplified for demonstration.
Instruments is reporting a memory leak of **CFStringCreateMutable** and **CFStringAppendFormat**.

```
CFStringRef CFDataToString(CFDataRef data)
{
    UInt8* buf = malloc(CFDataGetLength(data));

    CFDataGetBytes(data, CFRangeMake(0, CFDataGetLength(data)), buf);

    CFMutableStringRef output = CFStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFDataGetLength(data) * 2);

    for(int i = 0; i < CFDataGetLength(data); i++) {
        CFStringAppendFormat(output, NULL, CFSTR("%02x"), buf[i]);
    }

    free(buf);
    CFRelease(data);

    return output;
}    

CFDataRef hmac(CFStringRef key, CFStringRef data)
{
    const char *cKey  = CFStringGetCStringPtr(key, CFStringGetSystemEncoding());
    const char *cData = CFStringGetCStringPtr(data, CFStringGetSystemEncoding());
    unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
    CFDataRef HMAC = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, cHMAC, sizeof(cHMAC));

    return HMAC;
}

CFDictionaryRef buildRequest(CFMutableDictionaryRef params)
{
    CFMutableStringRef signature = CFStringCreateMutable(NULL, 0);
    CFStringAppend(signature, CFDataToString(hmac(CFSTR("mykey"), CFSTR("mydata"))));

    CFDictionarySetValue(params, CFSTR("signature"), signature);


    // ....
    // ....       


    return params;
}

void request(CFMutableDictionaryRef params)
{
    params = buildRequest(params);

    // ... Run request

    CFRelease(params);
}
```

Instruments output...

[image]

[image]

Comment: And where exactly are you releasing the allocated data? I believe to recall, that CFStringCreate...creates strings, which have to be released by 'CFRelease' once you're done with them. CFDataToString 'vanishes' in 'CFStringAppend' without being released. Save the pointer somewhere and release it once you've appended it.

Comment: That was the issue, creating a pointer to the CFStringRef returned by CFDataToString and then releasing once appended to signature CFStringRef solves the memory leak. I thought `CFStringAppend` released the string passed to it.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this [CFString memory leak][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14968063/3458862

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just once more as answer.

All data allocated with a `Create` method puts the responsibility for releasing the data to the programmer. In this regard, it's the same as calling `malloc`. No method will ever release this data, unless explicitely stated in the documentation.

To solve your problem, save a reference to the 'Created' (Allocated) data in the method which receives it and release it at the end of the method, once you're done with it.