# Instruments CFString (store)

Tags: ios, instruments, cfstring

I am running instruments on an app. According to instruments there aren't any leaks detected.

However, the category `CFString (store)` keeps rising.  Does anyone know what `CFString (store)` is?

Could this mean I have a leak?

Comment: Maybe you should take a look  at this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14968063/3458862

Answer (score 1):

It appears this issue may have been a cache issue in NSURL in iOS 6.1, based upon some other information I came across while working on something else.

I encountered this while working with AFNetworking 1.3. When I updated the App target to iOS 7, the issue no longer exists.

I still have no idea what (store) means behind CFString, perhaps it refers to storage like cache or something.  I've not found any documentation with a precise definition.